image container not move outside of the frame in flutter
I have one image container, and on this image container, there is one frame container with a fixed position. However, when the image container moves, if the boundaries of the frame container and the image container are the same, than not move in that direction.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CropImagePage(),
    );
  }
}

class CropImagePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CropImagePageState createState() => _CropImagePageState();
}

class _CropImagePageState extends State<CropImagePage> {
  Offset _position = Offset.zero;
  bool _canDrag = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Crop Image'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              left: _position.dx,
              top: _position.dy,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  if (!_canDrag) return;

                  setState(() {
                    _position += details.delta;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                  ),
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://via.placeholder.com/300',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 50,
              top: 50,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    _canDrag = false;
                  });
                },
                onPanEnd: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    _canDrag = true;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} 

I have one image container, and on this image container, there is one frame container with a fixed position. However, when the image container moves, if the boundaries of the frame container and the image container are the same, than not move in that direction.

setting _canDrag = false and _canDrag = true is pointless because both GestureDetectors cannot call theirs onPanUpdate callbacks at the same time, what do you want to achieve with that code? do you want to simply ignore the events when touching small 100x100 pox? if so use IgnorePointer



Stack(
clipBehavior: Clip.none, // Set overflow to visible
children: < Widget > [
  Positioned(
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    child: GestureDetector( // Gesture detector is not necessary for overflow visible
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    ),
  ),
  Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: < Widget > [
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.photo),
        title: Text('Photos'),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    ],
  ),
],
), ),



You just need to set clip behavior to Clip.none

this is not work. I need the image container to move, while the small container remains fixed in its position inside the image container. If the borders of both containers are aligned, the movement in that direction should stop until their borders are no longer aligned.
